# How to generate truncated normally distributed random variables that fall within from 0 to 10?

Tags: r

I was wondering if there's a simple option to designate the **range of the variable from 0 to 10** on the generation of truncated normal distribution of random variables using `rnorm()` function.

Comment: do you mean truncated normal distribution?

Comment: I am not sure if this is called truncated normal distribution. I just want to generate 1000 random variables, all of them lie between 0 and 10.

Comment: But you asked for a *Normal distribution* between 0 and 10. It would be really easy to generate values from a *uniform* distribution between 0 and 10 (`runif(1000, min=0, max=10)`)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution This is a like to truncated normal distribution

Comment: @BenBolker, but isn't this following uniform distribution? Can I use `rnorm()` instead of `runif()` because I want it from normal distribution.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding, yeah, probably it sounds like truncated normal distribution. so you are suggesting `truncnorm’.

Comment: See my answer.  We're having trouble answering because what you asked for is mathematically impossible, so we're trying to come up with a reasonable alternative/guessing exactly what you do want

Comment: Mathematically the _normal distribution_ doesn't have upper and lower limits, like the _uniform distribution_ has. If you enforce it (one way or another), you no longer have a normal distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is mathematically impossible — Normal distributions are always defined over the entire real line, from -∞ to ∞ — so you might need to give us a little bit more context about what you want to do.

You could choose a scale such that (say) 95% of the probability density of the Normal lay between 0 and 10, then sample from the corresponding [*truncated normal* distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution), e.g.:

```r
## in the normal distribution, 95%  lies within ± 2 SD, we want
## 95% to lies within ± 5:
sd0 <- 5/(2*1.96) # 
library(truncnorm)
set.seed(101)
r <- rtruncnorm(1e5, a=0, b=10, mean=5, sd=sd0)
hist(r)
```

[image: hist of truncated normal]

Technically you could get closer and closer to a true Normal distribution by making the standard deviation tiny: for example `rnorm(1000, 5, sd=1e-6)` will give you 1000 values that will generally lie between 4.9999 and 5.0000, and the probability of getting a value <0 or >10 is vanishingly small — but I'm guessing that's not what you actually want.

If you wanted to avoid the `truncnorm` package and don't mind inefficiency you could pick more values than you needed (say, 1200) using `rnorm()`, throw away the ones <0 or >10 (on average this will only be about 5% of the sample if you use the values above), then take the first 1000 of the ones that are left.

Answer (score 2):

Can you clarify what you mean by on the scale of zero to ten? A random normal variable will have a given mean and standard deviation. For example, by default the mean will be 0, and 1% of the values will fall within [-1, 1]. However, they can theoretically be as large or as small as you can imagine, albeit with decreasing probability.

Perhaps you want a uniform distribution, i.e. choosing a random number somewhere in the interval [0, 10]? You could do so with `runif(1, min = 0, max = 10)`. This would produce a result equally likely anywhere in the interval.